# How to check if a variable is an integer in Jinja2?

Tags: jinja2

The aim is to check whether a variable is an integer and if that is true insert hello.

**Attempt**

```
{% if int(variable) %} hello {% endif %}
```

**Result**

```
'int' is undefined"
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### To use the Jinja2 `int` builtin filter (which tries to cast the value to an int):

You need to use the filter format, like this:

```
{% if variable|int != 0 %} hello {% endif %}
```

By default, if casting to int fails it returns 0, but you can change this by specifying a different default value as the first parameter. Here I've changed it to -1 for a case where 0 might be a valid value for `variable`.

```
{% if variable|int(-1) != -1 %} hello {% endif %}
```

see the: [Jinja2 Docs - int builtin filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#int) for more info

#### To use the Jinja2 `number` builtin test (which returns true if the variable is already a number):

a better solution, rather than using the `int` filter (which will cast a integer like string to an int) is to use the builtin test `number`, like this:

```
{% if variable is number %} hello {% endif %}
```

see the: [Jinja2 Docs - number builtin test](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#number)

Comment: `{% if variable|number %}` raises `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'number'`, but `{% if variable is number %}` does the job

Answer (score 12):

For anyone using Salt, this did not work for me when put is saltstack state.

```
{% if variable|number %} hello {% endif %}
```

This did work however:

```
{% if variable is number %} hello {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3):

None of these solutions worked for me, however this did :

`{% if variable is even or variable is odd %}`